# Spring MVC can't get parameter when parameter name or value just one letter

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestparam/map")  
public String map(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {  
    System.out.println("get map params: " + params);  
    return "param";  
}
```

URL：

```
/requestparam/map?p1=1&p2=2&p=3&p4=44
```

Output result:

```
get map params: {p1=, p4=44, p2=, =}
```

I also print the `HtptServletRequest.getParametersMap()`, but the result is the same.
The Spring MVC version is 3.2.0.RELEASE.
Why this happen and how can I solve it?, thanks!

Comment: you can check this example http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/07/accessing-request-parameters-using.html#.UQi5kR1vps9

Comment: I find the answer,after change to JDK6 is OK(before tomcat bind to jdk5).